# Which character's stealth can be detected by green wards?

Tags: league-of-legends

Which character's stealth can be detected by green wards? (note: not purple which normally used for detecting stealth). For example I know Wukong can be detected by green wards during his clone, but I was curious if they where other champions that can be detected in a similar fashion?

Edit: Ah my bad I thought Wukong could be detected. but I believe that his stealth was short was the reason the green ward detected him, thank you for your answers though.

Comment: Are you sure green wards can detect a stealth Wukong...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, Sight Wards (Green wards) do not detect stealthed units at all. Only Vision Wards (Purple wards) can detect a stealth unit, including Wukong's clone, Shaco's Deceive and Twitch/Evelynn's stealth etc.

Answer (score 1):

None of them can be whilst in stealth...all of them can be whilst OUT of stealth. As far as i'm aware Wukong is not findable with green wards.

Answer (score 0):

Stealth cannot be detected by Green wards, however good placement of green wards can notify you to a stealth champion heading your way before they enter stealth. This is especially effective against Shaco, talon, and Vayne because of their very short stealth durations.

Answer (score 0):

Green wards cannot detect any kind of stealth, they can't detect Wukongs stealth either.

The only consumeables that can detect spells is oracles elixir and vision wards

Answer (score 0):

Pink wards and Oracles are the only consumables that will show you invisible champions. Green wards will not do this for you at any point, but if they are all you have you might want to place them further along than usual (enemy tribush/by blue buff/by dragon, etc depending where you are) so that you can try and see them before they enter stealth.